# Mysql: split string into characters and number

Tags: mysql, regex, string

I would like to split string into two parts - characters and number.
Strings look like this:

`[A-Z]{1,2}0*[0-9]+`

or:

`one or two characters, then variable number of zeroes, and variable number of numbers`

Examples:

`'A123' => ('A', '123')`

`'YZ00000456' => ('YZ', '456')`

I wish to split those strings into characters (`A`,`YZ`) and numbers, not starting with zero (`123`,`456`).

I would prefer to do this in SQL, because it is part of bigger block of statements I want to have inside procedure.

Comment: Just a heads up, `*` is not the same as `+`

Comment: sure, but in this case the regex is correct. none or some zeroes, followed by at least one number > 0

Comment: Minor point:  that regex allows `A0`. If that shouldn't be allowed, replace `[0-9]+` with `[1-9]+`

Comment: The question seems clear (enough) to me. But to make it unambiguous, add examples of input and output. `'A123'` => `('A', '123')`. `'YZ00000456'` => `('YZ', '456')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to create user-defined functions that goes through and look at each letter of the string and decide if it should be added to the return value or not.  Here are 2 functions that might work for you.

```
CREATE FUNCTION grab_chars(s varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(50)
BEGIN
  SET @str = s, @char = '',@return_str = '';
  WHILE LENGTH(@str) > 0 DO
     SET @char = LEFT(@str,1);
     IF ASCII(@char) BETWEEN ASCII('a') AND ASCII('z') OR
        ASCII(@char) BETWEEN ASCII('A') AND ASCII('Z') THEN
        SET @return_str = CONCAT(@return_str,@char);
     END IF;
     SET @str = RIGHT(@str,LENGTH(@str)-1);
  END WHILE;
  RETURN @return_str;
END/

CREATE FUNCTION grab_nums(s varchar(50))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  SET @str = s, @char = '',@return_str = '';
  WHILE LENGTH(@str) > 0 DO
     SET @char = LEFT(@str,1);
     IF ASCII(@char) BETWEEN ASCII('0') AND ASCII('9') THEN
        SET @return_str = CONCAT(@return_str,@char);
     END IF;
     SET @str = RIGHT(@str,LENGTH(@str)-1);
  END WHILE;
  RETURN CONVERT(@return_str,UNSIGNED);
END/
```

[sqlfiddle to show these functions in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcdb9/1)

Comment: Thanks @Tin Tran